# powershell and indexer property

Tags: powershell, properties, indexing, indexer

If an indexer in C# is expressed as: index[1, 1]. How would you express this with powershell?

To be more specific, I'm trying to use [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com) with Powershell to generate excel documents. However I'm having a problem select cells using its cell index property.

I posted a thread on [Epplus' discussion forum](http://epplus.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=235285) but I'm not entirely sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WorkBook.Cells` is an ExcelRange object that provides access to cell via [Indexers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02.aspx).

Indexers are syntactic sugar that don't translate directly to PowerShell, use this instead:

```
$WorkSheet.Cells.Item(1,1).Value = "Cell 1"
```